# Deleting row from view in xtensor

Tags: c++, numpy, xtensor

I have a 2D xtensor view, and i would like to remove a line from it with a known index. With numpy, there is the delete() method, with that, it is easy to do. Is there any similar way to do it with xtensor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not yet, that should be available in the next release (0.16.5 or 0.17.0) via dynamic_view and drop_slice new classes:

```cxx
xt::xtensor<int, 2> a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
auto v = xt::dynamic_view(a, xt::drop_slice(1), xt::all());
std::cout << v << std::endl;
```

The last line should print

```cxx
{{1, 2},
 {5, 6}}
```

EDIT (08/01/2018): xtensor 0.17.0 has been released, the syntax for building the dynamic view is:

```cxx
auto v = xt::dynamic_view(a, xt::drop(1), xt::all());
```

Comment: Do you know what is the expected release date?

Comment: That should be by the end of July.